# Can you explain a scanning session alterning between succesful scannings and Out of Memory errors?

Tags: debian, scanner, bugs

On *Debian 11*,

1. I do this first scanning attempt, below, and it succeeds:

```bash
scanimage --mode=Color --format=jpeg >mathematiques/arc_associes_rotation_symetrie_1.jpg
```

2. Then a second one, few seconds after, does an out of memory error

```bash
scanimage --mode=Color --format=jpeg >mathematiques/arc_associes_rotation_symetrie_2.jpg
```

```
scanimage: open of device escl:http://127.0.0.1:60000 failed: Out of memory
```

3. And another one, with sudo, also:

```bash
sudo scanimage --mode=Color --format=jpeg >mathematiques/arc_associes_rotation_symetrie_2.jpg
```

4. Eventually, I open the *Epson Scan* tool, and and it works

[image]

Comment: can you run `export LANG=C;  scanimage --mode=Color --format=jpeg >mathematiques/arc_associes_rotation_symetrie_1.jpg` and copy and paste the verbatim error message? This might contain interesting information. Also, make sure you have enough free disk space: `df -h mathematiques/` should show how much unused space is on that storage device.

Comment: Additionally : Do you get some swap space somewhere ? When going out of memory, do you think some processes running are being killed ? And also please post the output of *sudo sysctl -a | grep overcommit*

Comment: I have 1.8 To disk available and 39 Go RAM free by `df` and `free` command. I've lost my last error messages. As soon as the error reproduces, I will post them.

Comment: I've added the out of memory error message.

Comment: So… what about the output of *sudo sysctl -a | grep overcommit* ?

Comment: I would also attempt to use the -B option in order to increase the buffer size from default 32K to default 1M

Comment: The `sudo sysctl -a | grep overcommit` doesn't list anything. And the `-B` option wasn't successful too.